# $\operatorname{Coth}(\alpha_n a) \to i$ when $n \to \infty $

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence

I have a question about the following statement from the article

- Alves, M., Rivera, J.M., Sepúlveda, M., Villagrán, O.V. and Garay, M.Z., *The asymptotic behavior of the linear transmission problem in viscoelasticity*, Math. Nachr. **287** (2014) pp 483-497, doi:[10.1002/mana.201200319](https://doi.org/10.1002/mana.201200319), ([author pdf](http://www.im.ufrj.br/rivera/Art_Pub/ViscoLocal.pdf))

They state on page 8 that:

Let $\alpha = \dfrac{\rho_1\lambda^2}{\kappa_1 + i\kappa_2\lambda}$ where $\rho_1, \kappa_1, \kappa_2 > 0$. then
$$
\operatorname{Coth}(i\alpha L) \to 1, \ \ \text{ when } \ \ n \to \infty 
$$
where $L > 0$.

Well, firstly, I think they are changing $\alpha$ to $\alpha_{n}$ and leaving $n$ hidden. And doing some mathematical manipulations, I'm getting to

Let $x_n = \Re(\alpha_n L)$ and $y_n = \Im(\alpha_n L)$. Using some properties, I can get
$$
\operatorname{Coth}(i\alpha_n L) = \dfrac{\cos(x_n)\sin(x_n)}{\cosh^2 (y_n) - \cos^2(x_n)} - \dfrac{\tanh(y_n)} {\frac{\cos^2(x_n)}{\cosh^2 (y_n)} - 1}
$$

From the equality above can I conclude what I want? Why?

Comment: What variables depend on $n$, and how do they behave as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: somehow we try to avoid links to SciHub, I replaced it.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker even better is a full bibliographic entry with doi, to help those with subscriptions or trying to track down broken links, in addition to a free pdf from the author (and I know that SH asks for a doi on its landing page....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\al\alpha\newcommand\ka\kappa\newcommand\th\theta$First of all, you copied the expression for $\al$ incorrectly. On p. 489 of the paper linked by you (the fourth display from the bottom of the page), we find
$$\al=r(\la)e^{i\th/2},$$
where $\mathbb R\ni\la=\la_n\to\infty$,
$$r(\la):=\frac{\rho_1^{1/2}\la}{\sqrt[4]{\ka_1^2+\ka_2^2\la^2}}\to\infty,
\quad e^{i\th/2}\to\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}, 
$$
and $\rho_1,\ka_1,\ka_2$ are fixed positive real numbers.
So,
$$|e^{-2i\al L}|=|\exp(-2iLr(\la)e^{i\th/2})|
=\exp(\Re(-2iLr(\la)e^{i\th/2})) \\ 
=\exp(-(\sqrt2+o(1))\,Lr(\la))\to0.$$
Thus,
$$\coth(i\al L)=\frac{1+e^{-2i\al L}}{1-e^{-2i\al L}}\to\frac{1+0}{1-0}=1,$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: why $2i e^{i\theta/2} \to \sqrt{2} + o(1)$? because $2i e^{i\theta/2} \to i\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}$ .  Is this  $i\sqrt{2}$ not important?

Comment: @jokadeka055 : This limit transition is of course incorrect, and I did not use it. Instead, here I used $|\exp(a+ib)|=e^a$ for real $a,b$. I have added this detail now.